# Unknown column 'mush' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

I was testing a simple employee application and got this ***Unknown column 'mush' in 'where clause'*** error. There is someone called 'mush' in the name's column.

Here's my code

```
 <?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "myuser", "mypass") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("peoplesdb") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Retrieves data from MySQL 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = $_GET[name]") or die(mysql_error()); 
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>First Name:</th>";
echo " <td>Last Name</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th rowspan=\"3\"><img src=\"../about/images/".$data['photo']."\" width=\"205\" height=\"205\" alt=\"\" title=\"\"></th>";

echo $data['name'];
echo "<td>".$data['name'] ."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$data['lastname'] ."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

The aim was to display the detail on a table with a picture to the left of the table.
Here's how I tried calling the application:

```
http://localhost:8080/displaymembers.php?name=mush.
```

I have a table which contains these columns:

*name, photo, telephone, lastname and dob.*

Is there anything I'm going wrong that stops the details from displaying? I would like your help.

Helen.

Comment: You must be working with a sled dog database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to quote your inputs, second you need to escape them:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = '".
   mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['name'] ) ."'");
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The error message has now stopped, but nothing seems to be displaying in the table. I can't see any error message. Is there's anything that's stopping it displaying? I even tried using echo $data['name']; but no output :(

Comment: You need to do `$data_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);` - the first row will be in `$data_array`. If you are expecting more than one row you should use a `while()` loop.

Comment: Thanks @Jonny Keogh, that did it. You guys are simply awesome. Thanks again for your amazing help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose it in quotes - e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = '{$_GET[name]}'
```

I would also suggest you use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string):

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']) . "';") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: The above will work, but it'll trigger a warning, `Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'` - i.e. use `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])`

Comment: Oops. Just copied and pasted - didn't realise that the quotes were missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try those put single quotes around your variable.

`$_GET['name'];`

And use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to avoid SQL Injections.

Answer (score 1):

you should try

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE `name` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

as `name` may be reserved for mysql purposes, and I believe it is ...